# no community in liferay 6.1 CE

Tags: java, liferay

I can't find a button or an option to create a community in LifeRay 6.1 CE.

[image]

Comment: You may refer tutorial from liferay.com itself for each new version.
Also you can get most of the stuffs from liferay wiki and blogs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Communities have been renamed to sites in 6.1, as mentioned in this [blog post](http://www.liferay.com/web/jorge.ferrer/blog/-/blogs/7858337).

Comment: thx. It seams that the number of  material about liferay 6.1 CE is not too much, especially for Chinese :-)

Comment: If you're planning to do development in Liferay 6.1, I'd highly recommend "Liferay in Action" [link](http://www.manning.com/sezov/). All the material is based on 6.1.